# rosconsole DEBUG logger. How to use it?

Tags: ros, rviz, logger, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I would like to know how to correct interact with the log messages generated by ROS. I did some research about it but I could not find a satisfactory material. The situation that motivated this question was:

I am running a simple bagfile with scan data information. To avoid the problem with the difference of time between the machine and the scan data from the bagfile I used the flag **--clock** as suggested in the appropriate documentation, however I did not set the parameter **use_sim_time** to true. Because of this, when I try to see the scan data on rviz I receive the following message:

```
[ WARN] [1470408821.734840992]: MessageFilter [target=base_link ]: Dropped 100,00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

Because of this message I tried to somehow turn on the rosconsole logger to DEBUG but I realized that I did not know how to do it.

After this contextualization, I redo my question: How can I work correctly with the ROS's log messages, how can I have access to the messages printed from rviz and what is a best practice to handle with analogous situations?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241179/rosconsole-debug-logger.-how-to-use-it?/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rqt_logger_level` to adjust logger levels via a GUI:

```
rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level
```

You can also do it from the command line, via service calls:

```
rosservice list
rosservice call /rviz_123/get_loggers <tab><tab>
rosservice call /rviz_123/set_logger_level <tab><tab>
```

For the `set_logger_level` call, you'd then have to manually set `level` to `debug` and also pick a specific logger from the list returned by `get_loggers`

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-08-05**:
In the specific case of rviz (because it has an anonymous node name), there is a `--debug` option that initializes the logging level to debug. You'll still have to use the above options if rviz is already running.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2020-06-24**:
This has been updated to `--log-level-debug`